# How do I create a dual date entry in Angular 2 with Kendo UI?

Tags: date, angular, typescript, kendo-ui

I'm trying to create a ***dual date object*** in ***Angular2*** and I have no idea how it can be accomplished.

What I mean by a ***dual date object*** is basically creating a single instance of a date picker using Kendo UI ([screenshot of a date picker from Kendo UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVmtN.png)). Once it's clicked, two instances of the date object appears. The first is for 'Start date' and the second is for 'End Date'. The date object uses Kendo UI.

Basically it's for users to select a date range. I would really appreciate any help on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kendo UI DatePicker can work with one date only. For selecting a date range, use two widget instances.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datepicker/rangeselection

It is theoretically possible to use a [Kendo UI Popup](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/popup) with two [Calendar](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/calendar) instances inside, and store the two date values somewhere, according to your preferences.

```
<style>
  #popup > div {display: inline-block; }
  #textbox { width: 300px; } 
</style>

<p>Focus the textbox:</p>

<input id="textbox" class="k-textbox" />

<div id="popup">
  <div id="calendar1"></div>
  <div id="calendar2"></div>
</div>

<script>
  var textbox = $("#textbox");

  $("#popup").kendoPopup({
    anchor: textbox
  });
  $("#calendar1").kendoCalendar({
    change: updateTextBox
  });
  $("#calendar2").kendoCalendar({
    change: updateTextBox
  });
  textbox.focus(function(){
    $("#popup").data("kendoPopup").open();
  });

  function updateTextBox() {
    textbox.val("use the Calendars' value method here");
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! Will try those ways :) On a side note, how could I use a popup because only once it's **clicked**, I would need two instances of the date to appear?

Comment: @MitchellY I have updated my reply to better illustrate what I meant.

Comment: Thank you so much once again for the illustration. I had a better picture of how it's done.